# 'react-native-render-html' do not render <b></b> and <i></i> as expected on iOS but does on Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-render-html

I am using 'react-native-render-html' to render html from my admin panel app but on the react native application on my devices text is bold and italic in Android device and is not on iPhone. What could be the reason ?

[This is how it looks in Android, first 2 list items are bold and italic respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDS2g.jpg)

[and this is how it looks on iPhone, no bold and no italic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJXqU.png)

Following is the code i have used

```
<HTML
        html={story.item.summary}
        baseFontStyle={styles.summaryText}
        containerStyle={styles.summaryHTMLContainer}
      />
```

[This is what I get with console.log(story.item.summary)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHO8J.png)

Comment: Please add code sample you are using to solve your task.

Comment: Alex i have edited my question with some more details

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thank you but this is my first ever question on any platform so i was not familiar with these things. I am going to edit it again

Comment: @MuhammadAown To help you out, I will need to be able to fully reproduce your issue on my own computer. I need the version of the libraries you are using (react-native and react-native-render-html) and a minimal reproducible example, including the HTML snippet you are passing, and baseFontStyles.

First guess would be an issue with fonts, unrelated to this library. Could you reproduce the problem without react-native-render-html?